# A generalization of Hilbert's Inequality?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I have a maybe stupid question here... Hilbert's inequality holds for any pair $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ of complex sequences and says that
$$
\sum_m\sum_n\frac{|a_mb_n|}{n+m}\,\le\,\pi\left(\sum_m|a_m|^2\right)^{\frac 1 2}\left(\sum_n|b_n|^2\right)^{\frac 1 2}.
$$
If I put $c_{mn} := a_mb_n$, the sequence $(c_{mn})$ is "separated". The question is: Can I drop this? In other words, is it always true that
$$
\sum_m\sum_n\frac{|c_{mn}|}{n+m}\,\le\,C\left(\sum_m\sum_n|c_{mn}|^2\right)^{\frac 1 2},
$$
where $C > 0$ is some constant? I doubt that, but I don't have a counterexample here. Do you have one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A try for a counter-example. Take, for $s>1$, $\displaystyle c_{n,m}=\frac{1}{(n+m)^s}$. Then
$$\sum_{n,m\geq 1}\frac{c_{n,m}}{n+m}=\sum \frac{1}{(n+m)^{s+1}}=\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{k-1}{k^{s+1}}=\zeta(s)-\zeta(s+1)$$

and we have

$$\sum_{n,m\geq 1}c_{n,m}^2=\sum_{n,m\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+m)^{2s}}=\zeta(2s-1)-\zeta(2s)$$
If the inequality is true, we have 
$$\zeta(s)-\zeta(s+1)\leq C\sqrt{\zeta(2s-1)-\zeta(2s)}$$
Using that $$\zeta(2s-1)-\zeta(2s)\leq \zeta(2s-1)\leq \zeta(s)$$
(as $2s-1\geq s$) we get that $$\sqrt{\zeta(s)}(\sqrt{\zeta(s)}-C)\leq \zeta(s+1)$$ obviously this is not true as if $s\to 1$, $\zeta(s)\to +\infty$ and $\zeta(s+1)$ is bounded.

Comment: Very, very nice. Thanks a lot, Kelenner! Upvoted and checked.